# Export a set of rewriting rules from php to apache: is that possible?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a Drupal website that I'm migrating to a custom php cms.

I have two types of drupal links:

**node/123**

**title-of-my-link**

With the new custom version, and after a database import, I've got:

**content.php?id=852**

I'm resolving this with an Apache rewrite rule that sends everything to a php file that does a mysql query and forward everything.

**Here's my process:**

### .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./reenvio.php
```

### reenvio.php

```
//I get the part of the url that I need to and put it inside an $urlString variable, extracting just what is after the forwardslash symbol.

$x = $conectarDB->prepare("
    SELECT id, alias1, alias2
    FROM contenidos
    WHERE alias1 = ? OR alias2 = ?
");
$x->bindParam(1, $urlString);
$x->bindParam(2, $urlString);
$x->execute();
$urlDrupal = $x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$alias1 = strtolower($urlDrupal["alias1"]);
$alias2 = strtolower($urlDrupal["alias2"]);

//Then I do forward everything according to the id that I've found in the database that corresponds to the alias:

//I get the variables for the server first
$http = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
$sitio = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$id = $urlDrupal["contenidoID"];
$reenvioA = $http.'://'.$sitio.'/contenido.php?id='.$id;  

//and I do sent the user to the unfriendly link
header('Location: '.$reenvioA);
exit();
```

My question being:

### Is there a way to do that all into .htaccess?

Comment: What do you mean by 'export'? Would any of the [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) options work for you?

Comment: I mean the if-then-that rules that I have in the file, and how to manage the database queries...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm working in an if-else statement in dev that's not yet there. I'm reading about RewriteMap and it seems that I could achieve it with RewriteMap and [mod_dbd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dbd.html) . Thanks!!! (you should post an answer, so I can accept it)

Comment: I've been reading your other questions and I've modified this answer so it hopefully solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When having a lot of `RewriteRules` that conform to the same pattern, you can use [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html). 
`RewriteMap` supports lookup from a variety of sources, one being SQL with the use of [`mod_dbd`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dbd.html#connecting). However, if all your content has been already migrated and it's basically a static lookup, you can dump all your rules to a file and use another map type to avoid the `dbd` dependency.

A `RewriteMap` can only be defined in the `VirtualHost` context. If you don't have access to the main configuration this will not work for you.

First define your `Map` in the `VirtualHost` config and configure `dbd` if necessary (step omitted):

```
RewriteMap drupalmap "dbd:SELECT id FROM contenidos WHERE alias1 = %s OR alias2 = %s"
```

A lookup map takes a *Pattern* and a *Substitution*, just like `RewriteRule`, so if you go with a file-backed map you can just dump the result of `SELECT alias1, id FROM contenidos UNION SELECT alias2, id FROM contenidos`. The format is quite straightforward, but you have examples in [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt).

Then change the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond ${drupalmap:%1}  >""      # Apply the rule if there is a result
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ contenido.php?id=${drupalmap:$1}
```

If you don't have access to the main server config, and your mapping doesn't have any logic, the "dirty" solution can be to dump all mappings to `RewriteRule` and paste them in `.htaccess` so you end up with a bunch of

```
RewriteRule ^node/123$ contenido.php?id=852
RewriteRule ^title-of-my-link$ contenido.php?id=852
...
```

You can do this with a little script and the query suggested before but if you have *a lot* of rules this might have performance implications.